# Can I use Doctrine createNativeQuery to return a custom set of fields?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm using Symfony 6 and Doctrine 2.9 (doctrine/bundle) and am trying to populate a json endpoint that should return a set of records that are a combination of different fields across different entities, for example (Car, Dealership, Owner):

`[{car_id:1, car_color:'red', dealer:'Toms Cars', dealer_location:'Tucson', owner_previous: 'Joe Carowner'}]`

It seems like `createNativeQuery` should do the trick - if I build out the sql and run in on the db cli, records are returned. If I add the select statement to `createNativeQuery` - no results are returned.

It looks like I need to configure a `ResultSetMapping` to pass to the `createNativeQuery` method, but fwict, `ResultSetMapping` requires a defined entity to map the fields to - but in my case, there is no defined entity, I just want the sql to be run, and results returned.

Is there a way to do this within the `entityManager` structure? it seems like the point of running a 'native' query would be to simply return the results, and not require those results to be mapped to any other entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can! Quick example:

```php
    public function __construct(
        private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
    ) {
    }

    public function getCustomFields(int $ownerId): array
    {
        $result = $this->entityManager
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('c.car_id', 'c.car_color', 'd.dealer', 'd.dealer_location', 'o.owner_previous')  // use entity prop name, not fields from database
            ->from(Owner::class, 'o')
            ->leftJoin(Car::class, 'c', Join::WITH, 'c.carId = o.carId')
            ->leftJoin(Dealership::class, 'd', Join::WITH, 'd.dealershipId = c.carId')
            ->where('o.ownerId = :ownerId')
            ->setParameter('ownerId', $ownerId)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
 
        return $result;
    }
```

Firstly inject EntityManager via Dependency Injection in your repository class. Next, use `createQueryBuilder` instead. Then you can use your Doctrine Entity classes instead raw SQL. You can use any other method instead `getOneOrNullResult` for example `getArrayResult` or any other, depends on your needs.

Comment: Thanks @deoomen - this seems promising! 

How would you build this out for a many to many relationship, where there's a shared table? 

ie, if you wanted all of the cars of type Audi from all of the different Dealerships, where there's a shared 'car_dealership' table containing a car_id and dealership_id relationship, but no 'car_dealership' entity class to pass as the 1st arg to the leftJoin method?